# Why search query params does not get the first chosen option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Hello I have a problem with searchParams. The problem is that when I use filters i.e "Breakfast, Lunch,Dinner" it does not put the first chosen option to the URL bar. It is something like that. When I choose breakfast nothing happens, when I choose Lunch then I get only localhost/?Breakfast. But there is no lunch, nevertheless array of chosen option looks like `["Breakfast", "Lunch"]`. I think it is because of asynchronous setSearchParams but that is why I used "useEffect".

*EDIT I get this error when I choose filters

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.

```
const filtersTypes = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.recipe.filters.filterTypes
);
const filterLengths = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.recipe.filters.filterLengths
);
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const onChosenFilterHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const content = e.target.value;

  if (e.target.checked) {
    dispatch(
      recipeAction.addFilters({
        content: content,
        filterName: props.filterName,
      })
    );
  }

  if (!e.target.checked) {
    dispatch(
      recipeAction.removeFilters({
        content: content,
        filterName: props.filterName,
      })
    );
  }
};

let queryParamsString = "";

useEffect(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < filtersTypes.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(filtersTypes[i]);
    queryParamsString = queryParamsString + filtersTypes[i].toString();
  }

  setSearchParams(queryParamsString);
}, [filterLengths, filtersTypes, queryParamsString]);

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Text _notFirst={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} fontWeight="700">
      {props.filterTitle}
    </Text>
    <Stack pl={2} mt={1} spacing={1}>
      {props.options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <Checkbox
            key={option}
            value={option}
            onChange={onChosenFilterHandler}
          >
            <Text>{option}</Text>
          </Checkbox>
        );
      })}
    </Stack>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: `queryParamsString` isn't referenced anywhere else outside the `useEffect` callback so it doesn't appear to be a real dependency. Move it into the `useEffect` hook's callback. What you describe certainly sounds like a stale closure over whatever it is that you are logging. `setSearchParams` is a synchronous function, it's only dispatching a navigation action that updates the queryString part of the URL. If fixing the `queryParamsString` dependency issue doesn't resolve the problem, would it be possible to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect?

Comment: I solved that problem, thanks sir :).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very easy. In this loop

```
i <= filtersTypes.length - 1 instead i < filterTypes.length - 1
useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < filtersTypes.length - 1; i++) {
      console.log(filtersTypes[i]);
      queryParamsString = queryParamsString + filtersTypes[i].toString();
    }
```

This is ridiculous

Comment: To avoid array index issues you might want to use array methods, i.e. something like `queryParamsString = Object.values(filterTypes).join("")`.